# Calculus: Converge of a recursive series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

I'm going crazy to solve this problem:
I've a sequence defined by:
$$x_1 = 1$$
$$x_2 = 2$$
$$x_{n+2} = \frac{1}{2}(x_{n}+x_{n+1})$$

And I have to prove that this sequence converges and what is its limit (I know what the limit is, but I don't know how to prove it...).

I tried with induction but I stuck during the induction step $n=n+1 \implies 1\leq \frac{1}{2}(x_{n+1}+x_{n+2})\leq 2 $

Tips?

Comment: To clarify, what did you try with induction?

Comment: Yes, I copied the wrong part from my LaTeX draft,
and I tried to show that the series converges if it stays between 1 and 2 not only for some $n$ (in the base case 1), but also for $n+1$

Comment: That's not suficient for convergence. For instance $\left(\frac{(-1)^n+3}{2}\right)_{n\in \mathbb N}$ is between $1$ and $2$ and it doesn't converge. Instead try to prove that $\left(x_{2n}\right)_{\mathbb N}$ and $\left(x_{2n+1}\right)_{\mathbb N}$ both converge to the same limit.(Why is this enough?). To prove it prove that each of them is bounded and monotonic.

Comment: I believe something like what I described is what's intended, but it's much easier to just prove by induction that $$\forall n\in \mathbb N\left(x_n=\dfrac{4\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n+5}{3}\right).$$

Comment: @GitGud I understand that if the two subsequence converge to the same bound and have the same limits, then the original sequence converges to that bound as well and the limit is the same, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Use induction to prove the following explicit formula:

$x_n = \dfrac{1}{3} \left(5 + 4(-\frac{1}{2})^n\right)$

And use that to show that the sequence converges to $\frac{5}{3}$.

**Induction**: Base case: $n=1, n=2$ give the proper formulae.

$2x_{n+2} = \frac{1}{3} \left(5 + 4(-\frac{1}{2})^{n+1} + 5 + 4(- \frac{1}{2})^n \right)$

$2x_{n+2} = \frac{1}{3} \left(5 - 2(-\frac{1}{2})^{n} + 5 + 4(- \frac{1}{2})^n \right)$

$2x_{n+2} = \frac{1}{3} \left(10 + 2 (- \frac{1}{2})^n\right)$

$x_{n+2} = \frac{1}{3} \left(5 + 4(- \frac{1}{2})^{n+2} \right)$.

Comment: How can I prove it by induction? I can't figure a way to do it :/

Comment: @Giggi I'll update the answer.

Comment: Ok Thank you, just one thing: I don't get how you arrived to at $x_n=\frac{1}{3}(5+4(−\frac{1}{2})^n)$ formula

Comment: You do it by assuming $x_i$ has the form $r^i$ and then solving the recurrence relation.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $x_i$ has the form of $a^i$, so we have:

$$x_{n+2} = \dfrac{1}{2}(x_{n+1}+x_n) \implies a^{n+2}=\dfrac{1}{2}(a^{n+1}+a^{n})$$

Assuming $a\neq 0$ we have

$$a^{2}-\dfrac{a}{2}- \dfrac{1}{2}=0$$

solving the equation

$$a = \dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2} \pm \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{4}+2}}{2} \implies a_{r1} =1 \land a_{r2} = -\dfrac{1}{2}  $$

Now, we suppose that the general solution is a linear combination between this two answers

$$x_n=p a_{r1}^n + q a_{r2}^n \implies x_n = p  + q \left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

to get $p$ and $q$ simply replace the values with $n \in (1,2)$

$$x_1=p+q \left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right) = 1$$
$$x_2=p+q \left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^2 = 2$$

Solving the system we have $p=\dfrac{5}{3} \land q = \dfrac{4}{3} \therefore$

$$x_n = \dfrac{5}{3}  + \dfrac{4}{3} \left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^n$$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{5}{3}  + \dfrac{4}{3} \left(-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^n = \dfrac{5}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

First, note that if $n \mapsto x_n$ satisfies the equation, then so does $n \mapsto x_n-c$ for any constant $c$.

Second, notice that if we start with $x_2=-{1 \over 2} x_1$, then we have
$x_{n+1}=-{1 \over 2} x_n$ for all $n$, and so $x_n = -{1 \over 2}^{n-1} x_1$.

So, choose $c$ such that $(x_2-c) = -{1 \over 2} (x_1-c)$, which gives
$c={5 \over 3}$.

Then we have $(x_n-{5 \over 3}) = (-{1 \over 2})^{n}(1-{5 \over 3}) $,
or
$x_n = {5 \over 3} + (-{1 \over 2})^{n-1}(1-{5 \over 3})$.

**Note**: $1, -{1 \over 2}$ are roots of the equation $x^2={1 \over 2}(x+1)$,
and $x_1={5 \over 3}, x_2={5 \over 3}$ and
$x_1 = 1-{5 \over 3}, x_2 = 2-{5 \over 3}$ are corresponding eigenvectors.